# Relative error in differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

> Consider the following problem with; \begin{cases}
> y'(t)=3y(t)-3t  & \\
> y(0)=\frac13 
> \end{cases}
>
> If the initial value is replaced by $y(0)=\frac13+\epsilon$, compute the relative error of the solutions using the $L^2$-norm over the interval $[0,5]$

Using http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegratingFactor.html I obtained the following;

$\displaystyle y(t)=e^{3t}\int e^{-3t}(-3t)dt=e^{3t}\big(\frac{e^{-3t}(3t+1)}{3}+C\big)=Ce^{3t}+t+\frac13$

If $y(0)=\frac13\Rightarrow C=0$ and $\ y=t+\frac13$

If $y(0)=\frac13+\epsilon\Rightarrow C=\epsilon$ and $\ y=\epsilon\cdot e^{3t}+t+\frac13$

but what is the $L^2$-norm, is it the euclidean norm, it must be dependant of the interval, do I have to choose the t-value with the biggest error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $L^2$ norm of a function $f$ on an interval $[a,b]$ is

$$
\left( \int_a^b f^2(t) \,dt \right)^{1/2}.
$$

The relative error is the $L^2$ norm of the *difference* of the two solutions.

The interval is specified as $[0,5]$, so calculate

$$
\left( \int_0^5 \left(\epsilon e^{3t} + t + \frac13 - \left(t + \frac13\right) \right)^2 \,dt \right)^{1/2} \\
= \left( \int_0^5 \left(\epsilon e^{3t}\right)^2 \,dt \right)^{1/2}= \epsilon\left( \int_0^5 e^{6t} \,dt \right)^{1/2}.
$$

Comment: Now it makes sense with the interval, thanks a lot.

Comment: I think, I have to divide this value by the $L^2$ norm of the original function $(t+1/3)$, then I get the relative error.

Comment: ahh yes, sorry for forgetting that. you are correct.